# Anythingslider ala jcarousel ( mutliple image display )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jcarousel, anythingslider

I am using  Anythingslider in one of my projects, and I want to display more than one image in the panel, the same way jCarousel does. I googled around and found nothing that can help. I appreciate any help ( code snippet or idea ). thanks

http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/ AnythingSlider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the images inside the list ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/AR49y/)):

```
<ul id="slider1">
 <li>
  <div class="images">
   <img src="image1.jpg" />
   <img src="image2.jpg" />
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
   <div class="images">
    <img src="image3.jpg" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" />
   </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Also make sure you have the [latest version](http://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/downloads).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm! I like your demo site, its a great tool! thanks again.